# R - How to initialize *or* add to ggplot, using only one function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a function in R that reads data off a website and plots 2 columns. How can I make it so that the first time I run the function it initializes a new graph, but then subsequent runs (which will be marked with a 'reset' parameter) will add a new set of points to the graph rather than overwriting the old one?

```
getdata<- function(team,year,reset=F){

#Retrieve/format Data
[..]

#Plot Data
if (reset==T)
{
    p <-ggplot(data, aes(x = no, y = pts)) +
        geom_path(colour="red", size=2) +
        geom_point(colour="black" ,size = 2, shape=21, fill="white") 
        return(p)
}
else
{
     add<-ggplot(data, aes(x = no, y = pts)) +
      geom_path(colour = "blue", size = 2) +
      geom_point(colour="black", size = 2, shape=21,  fill="white")             

              p <- p + add
      return(p)
}
```

I think my issue is similar to this posted here: [Adding line with points to a plot in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520758/adding-line-with-points-to-a-plot-in-ggplot2) but I'm having some trouble adding the it as a list to the currently existing plot.

I'm a beginner with R so might be doing something stupid!

Thanks for any help, been wrestling with this for a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that need to happen for this to work:

1. Your function needs as mechanism to store the previous plot
2. You want to add layers (e.g. `geom_point()`) to your plot, not an entire `ggplot` object

So here is a potential implementation (note, untested since your example is not reproducible):

```
make_getdata <- function() {                      # THIS FUNCTION RETURNS A FUNCTION
  p <- NULL                                       # WE WILL STORE PLOT HERE
  function(team,year,reset=F) {
    # get data
    if(reset || is.null(p)) {
      p <<- ggplot(data, aes(x = no, y = pts)) +  # NOTICE DOUBLE ARROW
        geom_path(colour="red", size=2) +
        geom_point(colour="black" ,size = 2, shape=21, fill="white") 
    } else {
      p <<- p +                                   # NOTICE DOUBLE ARROW
        geom_path(data=data, aes(x = no, y = pts), colour = "blue", size = 2) +
        geom_point(data=data, aes(x = no, y = pts), colour="black", size = 2, shape=21,  fill="white")
    }
    return(p)
} }
getdata <- make_getdata()   # this creates your `getdata` function and stores it in `getdata`
getdata(...)
```

The key here is we take advantage of R's scoping properties to create a persistent variable were we store the graph.  `make_getdata()` creates a function as well as a function environment.  That environment contains `p`, which we can use to store our plots with `<<-`.

Comment: Hey Brodie thanks for the reply.

Ok so I understand that using the double arrows declare p as a global variable so it's persistent, which helps me out. Could you please clarify your use of functions there. In particular line 1, 3 and 16? Why are we declaring the function twice and why do we use make_getdata first and then on line 16 set to getdata

Comment: @Nilly, please note that double arrows do not necessarily declare anything as a global variable.  What they do, is assign to the closest object in the enclosure ancestry.  In this case, it is `p` inside `make_getdata`, which is not in the global environment.  See discussion **[in this R bloggers article on closures](http://www.r-bloggers.com/closures-in-r-a-useful-abstraction/)**.

Comment: @Nilly, we are not declaring any functions twice.  We are first writing a function that produces another function.  The only reason we do this is so we can create an environment to store our `p` variable.  The return value of `make_get_data` is a function (which we store in `getdata`) that has a "private" parent environment (`make_get_data`'s environment) that contains a variable `p`, where we store our graph.

Comment: @Nilly, finally, this is relatively advanced R.  One way you can avoid it is by adding a `p` argument to your function, so that you keep passing back the plot to the function every time you call it, but that's kludgier.

Comment: Ok. So just to make sure I'm getting things properly. If I were to just use double arrows in _my_ code, it would declare p in the global environment. However you're using the first function as an 'environment wrapper' of sorts, which keeps the p persistent within the scope of that function.

Comment: +1 for the recommendation to include the plot as a variable to the function - this would avoid the necessity to sully the global environment without good reason. It would probably be a good idea to save previous plots in a list. `plots <- list(); plots$plot1 <- ...`

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen, what do you mean "sully the global environment without good reason"?  The whole point of this set-up is that the global environment is not sullied by creating the closure and storing the plots there, rather than in the global env.  Or are you referring to `make_getdata`?  I was thinking of making that anonymous, but it seemed too much to explain.

Comment: add the anonymous thing just for shits. Is the explanation similar to the answer in your anonymous file question?

Comment: @rawr, the anonymous thing would be: `getdata <- (function() { p <- NULL; #put rest of make_getdata code here})()`, so `make_getdata` doesn't exist as an explicit object anymore (hence anonymous).

Comment: so the syntax is just `name <- (something)()`?

Comment: @rawr, so long as `something` evaluates to a function.